# Oracle subpartition a subpartition

Tags: oracle, list, range, partitioning

I have 3 columns which I would like to partition by, let's call them

```
some_date DATE
some_type VARCHAR2
some_product VARCHAR2
```

I would like to partition by range using some_date, then subpartition by list using some_type, then subpartition that further by some_product.  Creating a subpartition for a subpartition is not possible in Oracle.  I'm on Oracle 11gR2.  Is there an eloquent way to mimic what I want to do?  A possible solution I have come up with is to range partition by two columns, some_date and some_type although it seems a bit messy since some_type is a VARCHAR2 and I have to care to add partitions in alphabetic order.

Comment: What is the reason to subpartition a subpartition? Is your table that huge? Perhaps a bitmap index provides the same benefits in terms of performance.

Comment: Maybe you can define subpartition on virtual column: `type_product VARCHAR2(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( 't'||some_type||'p'||some_product ) VIRTUAL` - but I am not sure whether this is possible.

Comment: Yes, the table is huge.  A bitmap index is out of the question because I need to truncate data before each which would pertain to a subpartition subpartion and a DELETE would simply be too slow.  Creating a virtual column does not give me the benefit of performance when querying the table by some_type and some_product.

Comment: Why do you need to delete any data for creating an index? And of course a virtual column would gain performance by partition pruning.

Comment: I sort of assumed you meant create a bitmap index instead of a subpartition but the point of the subpartition is that we would like to truncate it rather than DELETE.  I guess the virtual column wouldn't be such a bad idea, I'll try to go this route and see what problems I encounter.

Comment: How many values does `some_type` have? Is a composite partition of `range(some_date), list(some_type)` a possibility?

Comment: @APC there would be a few hundred million records if partitioned by range(some_date) and list(some_type) in the list(some_type) subpartition, that's why we need to subpartition down further.  Concatenating two VARCHAR columns is not that great of an idea because OBIEE will not build a query to use the virtual column with concatenation and partition pruning will not occur. I guess the initial design I mentioned in my post will have to stay.